# Angular 6 Redirect to actual component rather than home after AAD Authentication

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have a angular 6 application integrated with ASP.NET MVC (authentication enabled with AAD Application). I have authorization logic in app.component which works but there is one page for which no authorization logic. so when try to access the page https://localhost:4433/#/tracking, after AAD Authentication, the user is taken to home page (https://localhost:4433/#/home) instead of taking the user to tracking component

```
export const router: Routes = [

{ path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },    
{ path: 'Tracking/:id', component: TrackingComponent }    
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent }];
export const routes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router, { useHash: true });
```

here is the startup.auth.cs

```
  app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
            });

        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

How I can route the user to actual page rather than home page after authentication. 
Or I have to use the AADL.js with auth Guards

Comment: You should be using MSAL.js on the front-end and JWT authentication in the back-end. Then you'll have a chance to grab the current URL, store it somewhere, and redirect to that once the user has authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL is hard coded in AAD Application properties. It's a little tricky to define dynamic redirect URL.

You can leverage [@Azure/msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) package to enable your Angular app to authenticate with AAD. The config option `popUp` should meet your requirement. With this option, the login process happens in a popup. The page will not redirect after authentication.

Note, this package only officially support up to Angular 5. For Angular 6+, install `rxjs-compat` NPM module.